# Editing Items Inside Grid - Using Vaadin 7.7.4

Tags: java, web-applications, vaadin, vaadin7

I have grid in my Vaadin project. I need to edit the cell/s by click on the cell. I dont need buffered mode, but I need help with this.

My grid code:

```
    Grid grid = new Grid();

    IndexedContainer container = new IndexedContainer();

    grid.setContainerDataSource(container);

    container.addContainerProperty("March",String.class, "");
    container.addContainerProperty("January",String.class, "");
    container.addContainerProperty("February",String.class, "");

    grid.getColumn("March").setEditable(true);
    grid.getColumn("January").setEditable(true);
    grid.getColumn("February").setEditable(true);

    container.addItem(1);
    Item item = container.getItem(1);
    item.getItemProperty("March").setValue("01.03.2017");

    grid.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.NONE);

    //Here I want have my addItemClickListener
    grid.addItemClickListener(event ->
    Notification.show("Y: " + event.getPropertyId() + " X: " + event.getItemId()));
```

I want change the cell "01.03.2017" E.G to "Something else". Or add a new data to the free cells from other Container property. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `grid.setEditorEnabled(true);`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16937400)

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz Of course it does, by adding this line he will be able to edit cells by clicking on them.

Comment: @Oleg - your advice may be good but please add some explanation. This will enable future readers to decide if your code snippet is helpful for their situation as well.

Comment: @0X0nosugar I would love to but I really don't know what can I add. If you want to edit cells in a `Grid` when you click on a cell you need to call `setEditorEnabled(true);` that's all there is to it.

Comment: If this is the case, never mind. I just thought that adding some explanation might get your answer out of the Review queue.

Comment: @0X0nosugar Thanks, looks like it's out saved by Michelle.